# SocketException: Permission denied Running Tomcat8 on Openshift

Tags: java, openshift, tomcat8

I'm running Tomcat 8 on a diy cartridge on OpenShift. When running Tomcat I get

```
23-Oct-2015 08:16:51.191 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-15089]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-15089]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    ... 13 more
```

I've tried changing the port to several different types within the valid range, but it seems to make no difference. Notice that the exception is not an "already in use" one, but a permission denied.

On a related note when trying to run netsat I receive this

```
/proc/net/tcp: Permission denied
```

I'm thinking this must be some kind of permissions problem but I'm not sure. It seems I should have all the access I need by sshing into my app, but I'm not sure again.

Comment: Check your policy fila (java.policy) and look out for socket permissions. e.g. grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1024-65535",
        "connect,accept";};